# What is the concept behind "tty" in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, history

Where did the terminology "tty" come from in Linux?

Answer (score 50):

As [Danny has stated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5424/63264) `tty` is **teletype terminals**. The fact is that most of us have used it many times, but few of us have gone so far as to understand it. Here is a very good article which gives us a basic understanding of TTYs in Linux.

[The TTY Demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php)

Answer (score 13):

This is likely to be a reference to teletype terminals, which would have been used in the early(ish) days of computers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter

Comment: Specifically http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletypewriter